# Display flask variables simultaneously in html template

Tags: python, html, flask

I have 2 separate forms on a html template called queries.html, one for inputting a company name and one for inputting keywords as seen below.

```
 <form method="POST">  
   <p>Enter Company Name:</p>
   <p><input type="text" name="company_name"></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
 </form>

  <p> Name: {{ name }} </p>


 <form method="POST">  
    <p>Enter Keywords:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="keywords"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
 </form>

   <p> Keywords: {{ keywords }}</p>
```

I want to be able to display the form input in the paragraph tags seen below each form. Below is the relevant flask code:

```
@app.route('/queries/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def queries():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form.get('company_name')
        keywords = request.form.get('keywords')
        return render_template('queries.html', name=name, keywords=keywords)
    return render_template('queries.html')
```

My problems is that when I enter information to one of the forms, the other variable resets to None. I'd like the information from each form to continue being displayed regardless of the other form submission. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by having a single form (both fields' data is posted back) and giving the two submit buttons different values. In the POST processing you will be able to identify which button was clicked and process the data accordingly.

For example:

```
<form method="POST">
   <p>Enter Company Name:</p>
   <p><input type="text" name="company_name"></p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="company"></p>

    <p> Name: {{ name }} </p>


    <p>Enter Keywords:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="keywords"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="keywords"></p>
 </form>

 <p> Keywords: {{ keywords }}</p>


@app.route('/queries/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def queries():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        name = request.form.get('company_name')
        keywords = request.form.get('keywords')

        if request.form['submit'] == 'company':
            # process company submit
            return render_template('queries.html', name=name, keywords=keywords)

        if request.form['submit'] == 'keywords':
            # process keywords submit
            return render_template('queries.html', name=name, keywords=keywords)

        return render_template('queries.html', name=name, keywords=keywords)

    return render_template('queries.html')
```

Comment: This gives 400 Bad Request error for both inputs now so neither will work